# 1st and 2nd Order Power Query Refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 4 Excel workbooks, connected using Excel's Power Query in Excel 2016. I am going to give reference to each workbook as A, B, C, and D for ease of reading and understanding.

**Context:**

Workbooks A and B are source workbooks, where users enter data into table objects. Important to note that these workbooks connect to another external workbook with a Power Query connection, and also holds traditional links (in the sense of a cell equals another cell in another workbook) to other workbooks too.

Workbook C is a 'summary' workbook that connects to both A and B, appends those connections and outputs the data in pivot tables.

Workbook D is a workbook that connects to workbook C using Power Query.

I have included a schematic below:

[image]

**Objective:**

I need to be able to refresh the Query connection in workbook D that will pull the latest data from workbooks A and B.

**Current research/ testing:**

As per my current research and testing, it seems query refresh is only 1st order i.e. refreshing the query in workbook D will pull the latest data in workbook C, but not workbooks A and B. The user would need to open workbook C and refresh the queries made to workbooks A and B, and then only refresh workbook D. The current VBA:

`Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

This method is also not inclusive of the links, whereby these would have to also be updated independantly of the queries, namely using:

`ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="C:\Users\deadevil\Desktop\Test1.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks`

The absolute work around at the moment is to build some VBA that opens workbooks A and B and refreshing accordingly when the user wants to refresh workbook D. I am happy to build this out, but am hoping someone with a deeper understanding of Power Query would know a better approach!

Is there a way to get this refresh functionality of '2nd order'?

Comment: That is, as far as I know, the only option you have with this setup.

Comment: Is there any other way to set these up @Rory?

Comment: They'd need to be one workbook rather than 4. Otherwise, you'd need to try and rewrite D's query to directly link to all the data sources and essentially replicate all the necessary work done by A,B and C.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way it is currently, but trying to streamline as it's quite admin intensive. Cheers for the help!